# Monitor activity to an IP Address - Windows 2003 and 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, monitoring, ip, network-monitoring

We are about to decommission a server that was used for email routing.

We have a collection of web servers that did use it.

I would like to setup some network traffic monitoring on the web servers to see if any of them are still accessing the IP address of the server we are about to decommission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded and installed [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f)

On to the web servers.

Then run it and set the Display Filter to the IP address of the email routing server:

> IPv4.Address == XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX